# set annotated csv for grafana's influx uploader

Tags: csv, grafana, influxdb

Trying to change a csv to an "annotated csv", in order to manually upload a file into the Grafana's influx uploader.

Says "
Failed to upload the selected CSV: The CSV could not be parsed. Please make sure that the CSV was in Annotated Format
"

manual is here : https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/write-data/developer-tools/csv/#csv-annotations

My (miss-annotated) csv is :

```
#constant measurement,datatest
#datatype dateTime:number,long,long,string
time,temp,raw,SN
1539250260,21,409,ABC3
1539250985,27,718,ABC1
1539251114,25,496,ABC2
1539251168,22,751,ABC3
1539251893,29,725,ABC1
1539252019,28,489,ABC2
1539252076,26,753,ABC3
1539252800,29,731,ABC1
1539252930,29,485,ABC2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
#constant measurement,datatest
#datatype time,long,long,string
time,temp,raw,SN
1539250260,21,409,ABC3
1539250985,27,718,ABC1
1539251114,25,496,ABC2
1539251168,22,751,ABC3
1539251893,29,725,ABC1
1539252019,28,489,ABC2
1539252076,26,753,ABC3
1539252800,29,731,ABC1
1539252930,29,485,ABC2
```

Comment: Hi Roberto. 
Thanks for answer. Result is not better :-/